# Backlinks stopped showing up in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, backlinks

Google Search Console (webmaster tools) has been finding backlinks for my site fine (at least 1 per day) up until 9 days ago. All of a sudden, for 9 days straight, Google webmaster tools shows no new backlinks.

I am 100% sure that there have been new backlinks created during this time. My ahrefs accounts is showing recent new backlinks. What could be the problem? How can I get Google Webmaster to start registering backlinks again?

Comment: First things first, online backlink sites are complete junk. They are very inaccurate and behind reality. Second, Google will report what it finds. It is not going out finding backlinks for your site and anyother site, it is indexing the Internet and when it finds a backlink, it will let you know but it will take a while. Google is not real-time nor does it want to be. Be patient and understand that Google will not find all of the backlinks for any site. It just won't.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not find only links, but they also crawl that URL(Assume link is not nofollow) and download webpage content, while other tools just find out links, so obviously Google will take some time to find out those links. So just wait, Google will surely find out those links in short days.

It's also depend on how frequently that webpage is crawled by Google, for example, if you place links on wikipedia article, then Google discover that URL immidetly, because they have more reputation a.k.a PageRank. So, if you build links on those pages, which are less crawled by Google, then it's take some time to reach those pages.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that Google doesn't always count every backlink you may have considering some of them could be considered illegitimate or gotten via "blackhat" practices.